# How to enforce key uniqueness in a temporal table?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

What is the best way to enforce key uniqueness in a temporal table (Oracle DBMS). A temporal table is one where all historical states are recorded with a time-span.

For example, we have a Key --> Value association like this ...

```
create table TEMPORAL_VALUES
    (KEY1               varchar2(99) not null,
     VALUE1             varchar2(99),
     START_PERIOD       date not null,
     END_PERIOD         date not null);
```

There are two constraints to enforce to do with the temporal nature of the table, to wit:

1. For each record we must have END_PERIOD > START_PERIOD. This is the period for which the Key->Value map is valid.
2. For each Key, there can't be any overlapping periods. The period includes the moment of the START_PERIOD, but excludes the exact moment of the END_PERIOD.
3. Constraint enforcement could be done either on row insert/update, or on commit. I don't really care, as long as it is impossible to commit invalid data.

I've been [informed that the best practice](http://harmfultriggers.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/the-materialized-view-approach-for.html) to enforce constraints like this is to use materialized views instead of triggers.

Please advise on what is the best way to achieve this?

The Oracle banner is ...

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
```

---

### What I have tried so far

I think that this solution is close, but it doesn't really work because 'on commit' is needed. Oracle doesn't seem capable of creating a materialized view of this complexity which refreshes on commit.

```
create materialized view OVERLAPPING_VALUES
  nologging cache build immediate 
  refresh complete on demand
  as select 'Wrong!'
      from
        (
        select KEY1, END_PERIOD,
               lead( START_PERIOD, 1) over (partition by KEY1 order by START_PERIOD) as NEXT_START
          from TEMPORAL_VALUES
        )
      where NEXT_START < END_PERIOD;
alter table OVERLAPPING_VALUES add CHECK( 0 = 1 );
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this work on commit to prevent invalid rows in TEMPORAL_VALUES?

Comment: Are you limited to Oracle? Postgres can do this quite efficiently with a new type of constraints called "exclusion constraint".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I am limited to Oracle. Even so, I would be interested to learn about Postgres exclusion constraints. Can you provide a link?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/pgconf/not-just-unique-exclusion-constraints  and http://thoughts.davisjeff.com/2010/09/25/exclusion-constraints-are-generalized-sql-unique/

Answer (score 3):

After some struggling, experimentation and guidance from [this forum post](http://community.oracle.com/thread/2604006),

```
drop table TEMPORAL_VALUE;
create table TEMPORAL_VALUE
    (KEY1                          varchar2(99) not null,
    VALUE1                         varchar2(99),
    START_PERIOD                   date not null,
    END_PERIOD                     date
    )
/
alter table TEMPORAL_VALUE add
  constraint CHECK_PERIOD check ( END_PERIOD is null or END_PERIOD > START_PERIOD)
/  
alter table TEMPORAL_VALUE add
  constraint PK_TEMPORAL_VALUE primary key (KEY1, START_PERIOD)
/
alter table TEMPORAL_VALUE add
  constraint UNIQUE_END_PERIOD unique (KEY1, END_PERIOD)
/
create materialized view log on TEMPORAL_VALUE with rowid;

drop materialized view OVERLAPPING_VALUES;

create materialized view OVERLAPPING_VALUES
  build immediate refresh fast on commit as
  select a.rowid a_rowid, b.rowid b_rowid
    from TEMPORAL_VALUE a, TEMPORAL_VALUE b
    where a.KEY1 = b.KEY1
      and a.rowid <> b.rowid
      and a.START_PERIOD <= b.START_PERIOD
      and (a.END_PERIOD is null or (a.END_PERIOD >  b.START_PERIOD));

alter table OVERLAPPING_VALUES add CHECK( 0 = 1 );
```

### Why does this work?

Why does this work, but my original posted view ...

```
select KEY1, END_PERIOD,
               lead( START_PERIOD, 1) over (partition by KEY1 order by START_PERIOD) as NEXT_START
          from TEMPORAL_VALUES
```

... will not be accepted as an On-Commit materialized view? Well, there answer is that there appears to be limits in the complexity of on-commit materialized views. The views must include the row id's or keys of the underlying table, and not be over some threshold of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique I've seen described for SQL Server (see [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/contiguous-time-periods/) and search for "Kuznetsov's History Table") which adds a third time column, `previous_end_period` that you can use to establish a foreign key on the table itself to enforce the constraint that the intervals can't overlap. I don't know if this can be adapted to Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for that. Kuznetsov's technique might work in oracle, with a bit of adaption, but it needs triggers to make sure the extra field is set to the correct value. In the end, I really wanted an implementation of Oracle's recommended best practice, which is Materialized Views.

Comment: Having said that, I really like Kuznetsov's method, and I would probably use it in a non-Oracle DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution Sean!

But I would add comments to your objects due to the complexity… something like:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN TEMPORAL_VALUE.KEY IS 'Each key may have at most only one value for any instant in time';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TEMPORAL_VALUE.START_PERIOD IS 'The period described includes the START_PERIOD date/time';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TEMPORAL_VALUE.END_PERIOD IS 'The period described does not included the END_PERIOD date/time. A null end period means until forever';

COMMENT ON COLUMN TEMPORAL_VALUE IS 'Integrity is enforced by the MATERIALIZED VIEW OVERLAPPING_VALUES';

COMMENT ON MATERIALIZED VIEW OVERLAPPING_VALUES IS 'Used to enforce the rule - each key may have at most only one value for any instant in time. This is an [on commit] mv, that holds any temporal values that overlaps another (for the same key), but the CHECK(0=1) constraint will raise an exception if any rows are found, stopping any commit that would break integrity';
```

I personally like to prefix all materialized view names with MV_ and views with V_

Interesting that you don’t allow START_PERIOD to be null. Most implementations would allow a null start and a non-null end to specify the period everything before, and null values for both bates to indicate a constant value for a key.

Comment: Thanks. Nice contribution.